# Deleting dataframe rows based on condition in datetime index

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, date, datetime, dataframe

I have a large dataframe with a size (43817, 6).  I have created a smaller dataframe consisting of the last two months by the following code:

```
test_df = df1.last('3M')
```

The reason why I chose '3M' is due to me running the code on the first of the 3rd month.  The index in the df is a datetimeindex.

Sample data below:

```
                   Scheduled_Start_Date    CRQ Change Class 
Scheduled_Start_Date                                                      
2018-05-25 13:00:00   2018-05-25 13:00:00  CRQ000000114908     Standard   
2018-05-25 15:00:00   2018-05-25 15:00:00  CRQ000000115436     Standard   
2018-05-25 15:00:00   2018-05-25 15:00:00  CRQ000000115429     Standard   
2018-05-25 16:00:00   2018-05-25 16:00:00  CRQ000000115491     Standard   
2018-05-25 18:00:00   2018-05-25 18:00:00  CRQ000000115572     Standard   
2018-05-26 17:00:00   2018-05-26 17:00:00  CRQ000000115495    Emergency   
2018-05-29 11:00:00   2018-05-29 11:00:00  CRQ000000115240     Standard   
2018-05-29 21:00:00   2018-05-29 21:00:00  CRQ000000115507    Emergency   
2018-05-31 15:00:00   2018-05-31 15:00:00  CRQ000000115516     Standard   
2018-06-01 05:00:00   2018-06-01 05:00:00  CRQ000000115466     Standard   
2018-06-01 09:00:00   2018-06-01 09:00:00  CRQ000000115085       Normal
```

What I am trying to do is get a complete view of all days in the last two months regardless of when I run the code and the only way I can think of is to delete any rows that have the current unwanted month in the datetimeindex that fall outside of the two month period.  For instance, if I run the code for the small dataframe on 6/1, it will return instances on 6/1 which I would need to delete.

Is there an easier way to get the last two (complete) months from a datetimeindex, regardless of when you run the code?

Comment: Just to understand clearly, if you run the code on 6/1, you want May and April and no entries from June?

Comment: Yes.  I am trying to only slice the previous two months of data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the current month data from the `df` and then look for last 2 months. After looking for last 2 months and removing current month and then look for one more month can be messy.:

```
import datetime as dt
current_month = dt.datetime.today().month
df.drop(df.loc[df.index.month==current_month].index).last('2M')
```

Consider below toy example:

```
i = pd.date_range(start='2018-04-01', freq='20D', end='2018-06-30')
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 10, 3, 4, 5]}, index=i)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
            A
2018-04-01  1
2018-04-21  10
2018-05-11  3
2018-05-31  4
2018-06-20  5
```

And then remove the current month data before looking for last `n` months of data.

```
import datetime as dt
current_month = dt.datetime.today().month
df.drop(df.loc[df.index.month==current_month].index).last('2M')
```

Output:

```
            A
2018-04-01  1
2018-04-21  10
2018-05-11  3
2018-05-31  4
```

Comment: @AlexCurtis Glad to help. Happy coding.